# How to find count of xpath expression with a condition in php?

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

HTML -

```
 <form action="http://192.168.64.2/file.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="venue" name="venue" />
```

XML -

```
<a>
<a1>
<author pid = "123"> </author>
<book>Book1</book>
</a1>
<a2>
<editor pid = "123"> </editor>
<book>Book2</book>
</a2>
</a>
```

Xpath in PHP -

```
<?php
$venue = $_GET['venue'];
$abc= new DomDocument();
$abc -> load("file.xml");
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($abc);
$xyz = $xpath -> evaluate ("count(//book[.='$venue'] and //author[@pid='123'] | //editor[@pid='123'] [parent::a1 or parent::a2] )");
echo $xyz;
?>
```

If the value entered in the form in HTML is found in the XML "book" tag and author id or editor id = 123 then I want to find count of book element. I am trying this but not getting the count and getting an error(syntax issue). Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parent can be a1 or a2 and both can have either editor or author, you could get multiple descendants using `self::`

To get the count, you could use the [query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) and get the [length](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php#domnodelist.props.length).

```
$venue = $_GET['venue'];
$abc= new DomDocument();
$abc->load("file.xml");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($abc);    
$expr = "/a/*[self::a1 or self::a2]/*[self::author or self::editor][@pid=\"123\"]/following-sibling::book[normalize-space(text()) = '" . $venue . "']";
$xyz = $xpath->query($expr);
echo $xyz->length;
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/HG7uH)